# How to update large table with jquery efficient

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have this code sample which updates cells within the html table.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < o.Rows.length; i++) {
        var row = $("tr").filter("[data-id='" + o.Rows[i].Id + "']");
        row.find("td:eq(3)").text(o.Rows[i].Status);
        row.find("td:eq(4)").text(o.Rows[i].Date);
    }
```

Executing of this sample of code takes a long time if `o.Rows.length` is 100 000. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Maybe return a complete table and replace the whole table.

Comment: Creating this table html on server side makes some trouble for me. I do that when there is no other way, but still I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't have a table with 100,000 rows, but...

You could speed up things a little bit by querying all of them upfront:

```
var trs = $('tr');

for (var i = 0, l = o.Rows.length; i < l; i++) {
  var tr = trs.eq(i);
  var o = o.Rows[i];
  tr.find('td:first').html(o.Status).next().html(o.Date);
}
```

Here's a jsperf showing it on 100 lines: http://jsperf.com/table-update/2